# Automatically Withdraw Email Approval in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketingcloudapi

We are managing all our email templates in an external system. Once a piece of content is approved, it is automatically created in SFMC.

What we want to do is automatically withdraw the approval on an email template if its expired in that external system.

Is it possible using API or SSJS ? I couldn't find any references

Comment: See here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/routes.html#approvals

Comment: According to @zuzannamj link above, you are looking specifically for https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/modifyApprovalItem.html and need to call it to remove approval from your external system once an item is no longer approved there.

Comment: Hi @FrançoisPerret, thanks for the reply. It is asking for some ObjectType parameter, what should I pass there?

Comment: The only input parameters I see is the approval ID and a Name, Description and 2 deadline related fields. ObjectType is in the response.